# Find lowest and highest values from Google Charts DataTable

Tags: jquery, google-visualization, google-datatable

I'm drawing a chart ([Google Charts API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable)) with this DataTable:

```
chart_data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
chart_data.addColumn('string','date');
chart_data.addColumn('number','value');

chart_data.addRows([
    ["10 May",0.23],
    ["11 May",0.26],
    ["12 May",0.29],
    ["13 May",0.23],
    ["14 May",0.21],
    ["15 May",0.25],
    ["16 May",0.28]
]);
```

I need to figure out which are the lowest and highest values of the **value** column in the DataTable. There are some functions called *google.visualization.data.max* but there is not any actual code example on how to implement it. Anybody has used that feature before? Or, has someone another solution for this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The function `getColumnRange` will return max and min. It also looks like you need to declare the column type and name for the number values.

```
chart_data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
chart_data.addColumn('string','date');
chart_data.addColumn('number','some number');

chart_data.addRows([
    ["10 May",0.23],
...
    ["16 May",0.28]
]);

alert("Max: " + chart_data.getColumnRange(1).max);
alert("Min: " + chart_data.getColumnRange(1).min);
```

Comment: Wow, I feel really dumb for having missed that method hehe. Thanks for the example, it worked perfectly!

Comment: You're welcome! Coming to Stack Overflow is the smart thing to do :)

Answer (score -1):

```
//If your fetching data from Mysql 

<script type="text/javascript">
 google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
 google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
 function drawChart() {
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

 ['LIFESTYLE','TECHNOLOGY LEVELS',{ role: 'style' }],
 <?php 
            $query = "SELECT question,useranswer from quiz";

             $exec = mysqli_query($con,$query);
             while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)){

             echo "['".$row['question']."',".$row['useranswer'].",'gold'],";
             }
             ?> 
 
 ]);
 data.getColumnRange(1).max;
//alert("Min: " + data.getColumnRange(1).min);

 var options = {
 title: 'LIFESTYLE CHART',
  // pieHole: 0.5,
  //         pieSliceTextStyle: {
  //           color: 'black',
  //         },
  //         legend: 'none'
 };
 var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart12"));
 chart.draw(data,options);
 }
    

    
    </script>
```

Comment: Hi there, anyone knows how to set color for getColumnRange(1).max